# Neo4j JSON-format for HTTP-endpoint is unspecified?

Tags: neo4j

The [only documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/3.5/introduction/) on Neo4j's HTTP-endpoint is given by a set of examples. Is there some set of formal documentation regarding the JSON-objects returned by the HTTP-endpoint? For example, a `Response`-object contains a `results`-key which is a sequence of `Rows`-objects, which may contain a `meta`-key ....

I know that asking for documentation is not part of SO, yet `neo4j` explicitly guides one to SO regarding any question.

---

It has been pointed out multiple times that the REST-API is being deprecated. The question is with respect to the HTTP-API, not the REST-API. The deprecation notice explicitly says

> ... Cypher and procedures should be used instead, either via the HTTP API, or via Bolt using the official drivers. ...